# Как автоматически получить данные через промежуток времени?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

У меня имеется PHP-код, который включает в себя `curl`-запрос к API; каким образом можно настроить скрипт, чтобы он ежеминутно отправлял запрос без участия человека (т.е. получал ответ от запроса и сохранял его в БД)?

Comment: cron, например ...

Comment: спасибо, взял на заметку